# Power bi scheduled refresh fails with error but manual refresh successfully completed

Tags: powerbi, dataset, refresh

Please help me in resolving the issue.

There are 6 reports in my workspace connecting to same database but only one report is facing the issue when it's dataset is refreshed. It's scheduled refresh fails with error

> Column '....' in table '....' contains a duplicate value '.....' and this is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship or for columns that are used as the primary key of a table. Table: ......

But when refreshed manually after an hour or so it's successful.

There was no issue initially but I can see the report fails daily in past one month.

My analysis

1. There are no duplicates in the column mentioned in the error message as we are using "distinct" in transform data. I have checked the data as well and i could see no duplicates.
2. I am not using incremental refresh
3. Gateway connection is working fine as the rest of the reports are being successfully refreshed and the status also shows as successful.

4.there are no changes being made to the database during the interval of scheduled and manual refresh.

I want to know what would cause this issue.

Comment: Can you share the Power Query for that table?